# Visitor visa Germany

Tags: germany, schengen-visas, applications

I and my younger sister are from Asian country and she studies in China. She would like to visit her friend (same nationality as us) who is studying in Germany, during holidays. I want to sponsor her during her visit but I am neither the host nor a German resident. Can I write a Letter of Commitment for her visa application and what kind of documents should I provide?

Comment: Where are you from? Where is your sister from?

Answer (score 1):

You should understand what sponsorship means in this context.

- You cannot make sure that your sister will leave the Schengen area, so promises *by you* will not help in this regard.
- Your sister will have to explain how she will afford the trip. If her explanation is that you will pay, she must explain why you would pay, and you must explain that you can afford her trip.

Comment: "Your sister will have to explain how she will afford the trip. If her explanation is that you will pay, she must explain why you would pay, and you must explain that you can afford her trip"  - this is our exact situation, we just don't know how to explain it. Will a letter from both of us and my bank statement will be suffice?

Comment: If he bank statement is no from a German bank and you re no resident in Germany this might not be enough, since German authorities have no reach in case demands arise.

Comment: @JannaB, multiple bank statements to show a pattern of expense and income. Compare [this one](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab/66105#66105) for UK visa.